# Email subject in Laravel 4

Tags: html, email, laravel-4

I have a simple problem which I couldn't solve until now, the problem is when the user asks for rest password, the email is sent correctly except one thing that the email, doesn't contain a Subject. And I want to add the subject but I wasn't able to do it.

here is the postRemind function in my controller:

```
 public function postRemind()
    {
        $this->reminderForm->validate(Input::only('email'));
        switch ($response = Password::remind(Input::only('email'))) {
            case Password::INVALID_USER:
                return Redirect::back()->with('error', Lang::get($response));
            case Password::REMINDER_SENT:
                return Redirect::back()->with('status', Lang::get($response));
        }
    }
```

and here is my blade :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Password Reset</h3>
    <div>
        You have requested password reset. Complete this form: {{ URL::to('password/reset', array($token)) }}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a closure to `Password::remind` where you can set the subject.

https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#password-reminders-and-reset

```php
public function postRemind()
{
    $this->reminderForm->validate(Input::only('email'));

    $response = Password::remind(Input::only('email'), function($message)
    {
        $message->subject('Password Reminder');
    });

    switch ($response) {
        case Password::INVALID_USER:
            return Redirect::back()->with('error', Lang::get($response));
        case Password::REMINDER_SENT:
            return Redirect::back()->with('status', Lang::get($response));
    }
}
```